# Extend multiple sources / indexes

Tags: sphinx

I have many web pages that are clones of each other. They have the exact same database
structure, just different data in different databases (each clone is for a different country so everything is
separated).

I would like to clean up my sphinx config file so that I don't duplicate the same queries
for every site.
I'd like to define a main source (with db auth info) for every clone, a common source for
every table I'd like to search, and then sources&indexes for every table and every clone.
But I'm not sure how exactly I should go about doing that.
I was thinking something among this lines:

```
index common_index
{
    # charset_type, stopwords, etc
}

source common_clone1
{
    # sql_host, sql_user, ...
}

source common_clone2
{
    # sql_host, sql_user, ...
}
# ...
source table1
{
    # sql_query, sql_attr_*, ...
}

source clone1_table1 : ???
{
    # ???
}
# ...
index clone1_table1 : common_index
{
    source: clone1_table1
    #path, ...
}
# ...
```

So you can see where I'm confused :)
I though I could do something like this:

`source clone1_table1 : table1, common_clone1 {}`

but it's not working obviously.

Basically what I'm asking is; is there any way to extend two sources/indexes?

If this isn't possible I'll be "forced" to write a script that will generate my sphinx config file to ease maintenance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this isn't possible (don't know if it's in the pipeline for the future). I'll have to resort to generating the config file with some sort of script.

I've created such a script, you can find it on GitHub: [sphinx generate config php](https://github.com/janhancic/sphinx-generate-config-php)